# FMC run for GFCI receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci, conduit, nec

I have a water heater room 5x8 that needs a GFCI receptacle added to the ceiling for a hot water recirculating pump. The heater is large and obviously hard plumbed in so cannot be moved and rigid conduit can not get around the back of it. Can FMC cable be used to get around it and strapped to the walls? This is San Diego commercial building. Work will be done professionally but I'm looking at the options. I've tried looking at the NEC but get lost. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nec Article 348 allows FMC to be used as a conduit system. However, NEC 348.12 (1) does not permit the use of FMC in wet locations. So assuming you water heater room is not wet during normal operations FMC can be used. However, if you determine that the wiring might cause a shock or burn hazard during non-normal working conditions some AHJ might have a problem with it.

Due to the fact that this is probably a short run and so material cost would not be a real factor, I would suggest you run it in LFNC "carflex" or LFMC "sealtite" and avoid any conflict.